# The following program is showing array index out of bound exception error

Tags: java

//program to find the maximum of two numbers

```
class Maxof2{

    public static void main(String args[]){
      //taking value as command line argument.
      //Converting String format to Integer value
      int i = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
      int j = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
      if(i > j)
        System.out.println(i+" is greater than "+j);
      else
        System.out.println(j+" is greater than "+i);
  }

}
```

Comment: could you print the command line used to launch this class ?

Comment: The else message is inaccurate: j is greater than *or equal to* i in that case.

Comment: Check length of args first